# Is it possible to display data through a id?

Tags: angularjs

My apologies for the abstract title. I'm in the proces of adding a friendship feature in my Rails/Angular application following [#163 Self-Referential Association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association?autoplay=true).

With the help of some other users here I've created the option to add friends, but I'm having some trouble displaying the correct data (name, etc) in a friendslist.

I have a `friendships` table,

```
create_table "friendships", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "friend_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

When a friend is added it creates a new record in the table with a user id and a friend id.

```
{"id":1,"user_id":1,"friend_id":2,"created_at":"2015-12-29T13:18:44.499Z","updated_at":"2015-12-29T13:18:44.499Z"},
{"id":2,"user_id":1,"friend_id":3,"created_at":"2015-12-29T13:18:45.463Z","updated_at":"2015-12-29T13:18:45.463Z"},
{"id":3,"user_id":1,"friend_id":4,"created_at":"2015-12-29T13:18:46.420Z","updated_at":"2015-12-29T13:18:46.420Z"}
```

In the `friendships_controller.rb` I have,

```
def index
  friend = current_user.friendships
  render :json => friend.to_json()
end
```

So I can see what `friend_id` is connected to a `user_id`. But if I want to display the friends in a ng-repeat I'm going to need more data.

The `friend_id` is the added users id. So if a user adds the 4th user to his friendslist the friend_id would be 4. So it possible to connect that `friend_id` to the `user_id` so I can then show the `{{ user.name }}` or do I need to add all the data like name, birthday etc to the parameters of the friend create function?

So for example I would add the friends name to the parameters so the JSON looks like this,

```
{"id":1,"user_id":1,"friend_id":2,"name":john,"created_at":"2015-12-29T13:18:44.499Z","updated_at":"2015-12-29T13:18:44.499Z"},
{"id":2,"user_id":1,"friend_id":3,"name":david,"created_at":"2015-12-29T13:18:45.463Z","updated_at":"2015-12-29T13:18:45.463Z"},
{"id":3,"user_id":1,"friend_id":4,"name":cash,"created_at":"2015-12-29T13:18:46.420Z","updated_at":"2015-12-29T13:18:46.420Z"}
```

Then I can do something like `ng-repeat friend in friendships` `{{ friend.name }}`

Comment: This looks more like a rails question than an angular question. To display information about potential new friends, you need this information. But that doesn't mean this information needs to be submitted to add a friend to the user: the ID of the new friend is sufficient, since based on this ID, on the server, you have all the friend information at your disposal, in the database.

Comment: Yea that could also be a solution. Not sure on how to make something like that work though.

Comment: What is the purpose of adding the user id (friend id) in the first place? I assume it relates to a users table of some sort? If that's the case (and it probably should be) just do a lookup based on the id, no need to save anything else as a friendship record

Comment: @aw04 could you explain a bit more about doing a lookup based on the id?

Comment: @PeterBoomsma I don't know the rails syntax off hand, but say the friend id relates to a users table that houses the user information. You would just take that friend id and run a query against the user table to grab that user record. At that point you have all the user information you need for that friend. It's a common concept, you should be able to find an example

Comment: @aw04 thanks. I'll check it out.